# VerticalAlignment for ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, vertical-alignment, arrangeoverride

iv'e got a custom panel which derives from stack panel

this panel has a layout logic which depends on the vertical Alignment of the Panel

CS :

```
  public class ReArrangeStackPanel : StackPanel
  {      
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        double delta =  this.VerticalAlignment == System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom 
                              ? CalcForBottom() : CalcForTop();                        

        ChildrenArrangement(delta);

        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }
```

1) i would expect the VerticalAligment Property of the ItemsPanel to be Inherited from 
the items control which it is a child of , it seems that it does not since it's set with the default 
"Stretch" Value .

2) Even when explicitly setting VerticalAlignment on the ItemsPanel , if i don't Hard code the value 
   the VerticalAlignment is set to "Stretch" in the ArrangeOverride scope , and only later (which i observe using snoop) is set with the "Bottom" value .

XAML :

a) doesn't work  : with binding  , the value is set but only after ArrangeOverride.

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:ReArrangeStackPanel 
                      VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=VerticalAlignment, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PipeControl}}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

b) works : Explicitly hard coding the value .

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <local:ReArrangeStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

in my Windows XAML the ItemsControl (PipeControl) is Set with the wanted VerticalAlignment .

so my questions :

1) why is the value not inherited ?

2) why is the value not set via binding before ArrangeOverride occurs ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: Maybe it's because [DataBind runs before Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), and the value isn't set until the parent is Rendered because typically the default style of sizing for WPF controls is based on the parent panel? You could probably put a Converter in your `VerticalAlignment` binding and check out what the bound value is at the time it's first evaluated.

Comment: @Rachel thanks , the ArrangeOverride is reached before the Converter . 
that answers number 2  .

any ideas why it does not inherit the value in the first place 
seeing is that they are both Framework element which one is the child of the other ?

Comment: If you comment out your `ArrangeOverride` method, or add `base.ArrangeOverride()` to it, does the value get inherited? It's possible the default value is actually set in the `ArrangeOverride` method, and you are overwriting that.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of [FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) is `Stretch`, so it makes sense that the default value for your `ReArrangeStackPanel.VerticalAlignment` class is also `Stretch`

Since the typical style of sizing for WPF controls is usually based on the parent panel, it's possible that the `ArrangeOverride` method of a `StackPanel` is what actually sets the `VerticalAlignment` property for a StackPanel, and you are overwriting that method.

If this is indeed the case, then you could ensure the default is set correctly by calling `base.ArrangeOverride()` in your `ArrangeOverride()` method

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
{
    base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);

    ...
}
```

As for why the binding isn't working, I suspect it's because [Rendering occurs after DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), so the `VerticalAlignment` property isn't set until after the parent control you are binding to has been Rendered.

You can verify if this is the case or not by putting a `Converter` in your `VerticalAlignment` binding and checking out what the value is when it gets evaluted.